# Where to add the JDBC driver in an app server?

Tags: java, jdbc, jboss

Where is the best place to add a JDBC driver when you are creating an application using Spring and deploying it to an app server? Am I right about adding a Maven dependency for it instead of putting it in the lib folder of the app server? You probably will run into issues during class loading if you need different versions of the driver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you want to configure your DataSource.

If you add the JDBC driver into your WAR/EAR file, then you shall use local DataSource (for example by using Apache DBCP) defined in your Spring configs.

If you add the JDBC driver to our application server lib folder, then you can configure the DataSource using the application server console too.

I prefer using application server console to configure my datasource, because many application servers (such as WebLogic) have lots of monitoring and configuring options on a DataSource, which is not easily available on a local DataSource (such as Apache DBCP).

Answer (score 1):

If possible use the Maven dependency route, this will import the library for the driver into the proper place.  It also ensures your working with the correct version of the driver and allows you to easily change that version without manually moving a .jar using the file system.  You also will not need to download the driver from the respective website since Maven will handle that for your.  Maven makes dependency management much easier, if your leveraging this technology you should take advantage of the simplicity it offers you.

This may not be possible if your using some database flavors (Oracle) since their drivers are not hosted on Maven Central.